# Capturing an image with Emgu - black image

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm a newbie in emgu cv and for a major project I'm trying to capture an image from a webcam and show it in an image box, but it's showing a black image.

What is wrong with the following code?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.Util;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Capture capture;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (capture == null)
               capture = new Capture();
            Image<Bgr,Byte> img=capture.QueryFrame();
            imageBox1.Image = img;                 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide more informations on your webcam, if it's laptop built-in or not and which emgu version you are using. Howewer try to run on of the Opencv example that make use of webcam if it does not work it's not an emgu issues but an opencv one.

Comment: Have you tried running one of the sample applications that come with Emgu? Such as the VideoSurveillance sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a minor mistake.

Use this instead:

Declare as global variable:

```
Capture capture = default(Capture);
```

Put this in load:

```
capture = new Capture(0);
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(grab);

t.Start();
```

Create a sub grab and put in,

```
do {
    ImageBox1.Image = capture.QueryFrame();
} while (true);
```

Cheers
Shreyas

Answer (score 0):

Call `QueryFrame()` twice, it works for me:

```
 if (capture == null)
           capture = new Capture();
 capture.QueryFrame();
 Image<Bgr,Byte> img=capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
 imageBox1.Image = img.Bitmap;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case Kaspersky AntiVirus was blocking the access to my webcam. After changing some security settings I was able to get emgu capture back working.