# Emgu Example.CameraCapture => black image

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Like the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093018/capturing-an-image-with-emgu-black-image), I am trying to capture images with Emgu. But even when running the examples I get a black image. I have tried changing the `new Capture()` to `new Capture(1)` all the way through 12... With no change.

I am using a Mac-book Pro 15" (early 2011) running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.

Note: The Green light next to the camera turns green when the program 'starts to capture' - The camera works in other applications so I don't think that it's the camera/configuration that's the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely an issue with OpenCV not supporting the particular driver that Windows selected for your iSight camera. According to [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS) list OpenCV supports the iSight camera, but only on Linux and Mac OSX.

You should check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720379/why-does-opencv-give-me-a-black-screen) related SO post. You may have some luck trying to use an external capture library like [Touchless](http://touchless.codeplex.com/). [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/webcam_c_sharp.aspx) is a little tutorial on CodeProject about it.

Hope that helps!